# Best way to parse Json?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to parse the data from a json and replace them in a table. And I'm using following code

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
data=obj.data;
totalRecord=obj.totalCount;
$.each(data,function(i,obj){
  for(var j in obj){
    switch(j){
            case 'priority':
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('.priority').val(obj[j]);
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('.hidden').val(obj['id']);
                break;
            case 'chkbox':
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('.chkbox').val(obj['id']);
                break;
            case 'status':
                var val=(this.j)?'active.gif':'deactive.gif';
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('img').attr('src','<?= base_url() ?>assets/grid/images/'+val);
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('img').attr('onClick','updateStatus(\''+obj['id']+'\',\''+obj[j]+'\')');
                break;
            case 'edit':
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).find('a').attr('href','index.php/main/edit/'+obj[j]);
                break;
            default:
                $("#td_"+i+"_"+j).html(obj[j])
                break;
            }
  }
});
```

But i think its bit slow. Is there other better ways to implement the same?

KrishNik

Comment: This is rather interpreting than parsing; `$.parseJSON` already does the parsing.

Comment: How big is the table (how many table rows or cells)?

Comment: You should really drop using `attr` in favor of direct property accessors. `attr` is pretty complex and uses loads of function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the parsing that's slowing you down. It could be that you're running a lot of jQuery selectors on a lot of objects, which can take time.

**EDIT:** Saw @pointy's answer. I didn't even notice that you were doing event delegation via DOM attributes. Yeeaah, that would probably run pretty slowly.

In fact, using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event delegation instead of assigning a click event to every single element would probably run even faster. Start by, instead of giving it the click event, give the element a reference to the object in question using jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```
case 'status':
    // Note that I switched it to this[j], since I suspect
    // using this.j was unintentional
    var val=(this[j])?'active.gif':'deactive.gif';
    $('#td_'+i+'_'+j).find('img').attr('src', '<?= base_url() ?>assets/grid/images/'+val).
        data('status_obj', obj);
```

Then, run the following only once in your entire script (obviously, untested).

```
$('td.status img').live('click', function () {
    var obj = $(this).data('status_obj');
    updateStatus(obj.id, obj.status);
});
```

This means that any `img` inside a `td.status` element (yep, I made up a new class name for you) that ever exists will, upon being clicked, run `updateStatus` with that `status_obj` data stored inside it.

Some smaller optimizations:

- Specify a tag name when looking up children, e.g. `find('span.priority')`, since jQuery can then loop through only children of that tag name instead of all children
- Or, in fact, give those children their own unique IDs to look up by, since `getElementById` is almost certain to run faster than looping through children.

Comment: Thank you matchu actually i want to mark all the answers as true.

Answer (score 2):

First, your JSON is **parsed** by that call to `$.parseJSON()`, and I bet that's *not* slow.  I bet that what *is* slow is the code that interprets the data structure and updates your DOM.

The first thing you need to do is stash that jQuery lookup in the inner loop. That'll help a little:

```
   for (var j in obj) {
     var cell = $('#td_' + i + '_' + j);
```

Now you can use "cell" instead of repeating that jQuery lookup.  (Won't help *that* much, but it's something.)

For setting up event handlers in a (potentially large) table, when what you want to handle are clicks (or whatever) on individual cells, you'd be **much** better off using jQuery's `.delegate()` function:

```
  case 'status':
    $('table').delegate('#td_' + i + '_' + j, 'click', function() {
      updateStatus(obj['id'], obj[j]);
    });
    break;
```

Note that your current code will re-attach that "onClick" handler each time it receives a "status" message in the data.  You could add a check to make sure you don't needlessly re-register that:

```
  case 'status':
    if (!$('table').data(i + '_' + j)) {
      $('table').delegate('#td_' + i + '_' + j, 'click', function() {
        updateStatus(obj['id'], obj[j]);
      });
      $('table').data(i + '_' + j, true);
    }
    break;
```

No matter how you roll it, iterating over a big data structure and updating lots of cells in a big table can be pretty slow, depending on your CSS etc and especially in old browsers (IE6).

Comment: I don't think the jQuery lookup is ever used more than once, though. It's DRYer to keep that reference at the top, but it shouldn't make a performance difference :/

Comment: Oh, man, but I didn't notice the `onClick` via `attr`. Well spotted, +1` :)

Comment: Well I agree, @Matchu; there are one or two of those "case" blocks that re-use the selector, but I suspect that the *real* slowness comes from making those changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable inputs. Yes the issue is with the code that interprets the data. And I have  made necessary changes. Its looking good.

Answer (score 1):

You are locating each elements for every iteration in the loop. Locate the cell and put the result in a variable outside the loop.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
var parsedData = obj.data;
var totalRecord = obj.totalCount;
$.each(parsedData, function(i, item) {
  for(var j in item) {
    var element = $("#td_"+i+"_"+j);
    switch(j) {
      case 'priority':
        element.find('.priority').val(item[j]);
        element.find('.hidden').val(item['id']);
        break;
      case 'chkbox':
        element.find('.chkbox').val(item['id']);
        break;
      case 'status':
        var val=(this.j)?'active.gif':'deactive.gif';
        element.find('img')
          .attr('src','<?= base_url() ?>assets/grid/images/'+val)
          .attr('onClick','updateStatus(\''+item['id']+'\',\''+item[j]+'\')');
        break;
      case 'edit':
        element.find('a').attr('href','index.php/main/edit/'+item[j]);
        break;
      default:
        element.html(item[j])
        break;
      }
    }
  });
```

Note that I renamed some variables. You were reusing variable names for different things, like reusing the `data` variable containing the JSON string to contain the parsed data, and the `obj` variable that contains the parsing result to contain a single item from the data.

I notices that you are using `this.j` at one point in the code. This is not the same as `item[j]` but `item['j']`, which might not be what's intended.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to speed it up is to put `$("#td_"+i+"_"+j)` in its own variable at the beginning of your for loop:

```
for(var j in obj){
   var tdElem = $("#td_"+i+"_"+j);
```

and use `tdElem` instead of `$("#td_"+i+"_"+j)` everywhere.